# Model for an existing database in Entity Framework Core. I need same as table name in context class

Tags: asp.net-core, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-core

Table name:

```
select * from CDS_DelegationRequest
```

After generating model folder with below command

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=1234;Database=DB;UID=DB;PWD=12345"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
        -OutputDir DBModels -Context CDSLMSContext -Tables CDS_DelegationRequest
```

in model folder it was created without underscore and camelcase.

```
public virtual DbSet<CdsDelegationRequest> CdsDelegationRequests { get; set; }
```

but I need same as SQL Server table name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific, that is, where do you need help while trying to do this? Show your efforts. That said, my advice is not to do this. When working in a programming language, adhere to the general code conventions for that language. It would be more useful to remove `CDS_` altogether and have a class name `DelegationRequest`. Maybe in a namespace named after the full name of the CDS abbreviation.

Comment: Well - what's stopping you from just simply **renaming** the generated class?? If you **really** insist on having a C# class with an underscore in its name - just go ahead! The code has been generated for you *as a starting point* - you can always adapt it to your own needs after generation .....

Answer (score 2):

You can add the table annotation above the class. this will tell EF what the table name in the database is

```
[Table("CDS_DelegationRequest")]
public class CdsDelegationRequests 
{
    .....
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @GertArnold no need to be toxic

Comment: Just drily stating a fact. They ask the reverse: "I need same as SQL Server table name" and reading between the sparse lines I suspect the question is: can this generation process be tweaked?